Saniflo for bathtub only
I am adding a bathroom to my basement and I already have rough in plumbing for toilet and sink. If I was going to add a bathtub the saniflo will drain and vent to which pipes in the picture? My best guess was the 3 inch vertical pipe is where discharge goes and the far right vertical pipe is where venting goes. Can provide additional details or pictures if needed. Thank you.

The far right also drains the sink

No it does not.
